# Within React, how to have a variable within a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following:

```
      <MenuItem
        primaryText={currentUserProfile.displayName || currentUserProfile.email}
        onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}
        leftIcon={<DropDownArrow color={textColor}/>}
        rightIcon={<img src="{currentUserProfile.displayName}" alt="Me" />}
        style={{color: textColor}}
      />
```

The rightIcon is not working as it is already within a {} --- how do I get a variable to work within a {}?

Comment: is that the right way to do it or a hack? just want to learn correctly...

Comment: thanks Andrew, want to post the answer so I can accept?

Comment: Wait, I don't think I read the question right. Are you saying the src variable isn't working?

Comment: the issue is I can't get rightIcon to render as desired, here is what is happening on the browser: `<img src="{currentUserProfile.displayName}" alt="Me" color="#757575" style="height: 24px; width: 24px; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; margin: 12px; right: 4px;">`

Comment: notice the source's variable `currentUserProfile.displayName` is not outputting the value of the variable.

Comment: You shouldn't be making it a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying your URL as `"{currentUserProfile.displayName}"` as a string literal. You should be using `rightIcon={<img src={currentUserProfile.displayName} alt="Me" />}`

EDIT:
Notice your quotation marks.